# JQuery Cycle Plugin Shuffle Right

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, cycle, shuffle

Fixed! Can't believe I didn't see this before:

```
$('#s4') 
        .before('<div id="nav">') 
        .cycle({ 
            fx:     'shuffle', 
            speed:  500, 
            shuffle: { top:15, left: 300 },
            timeout: 0, 
            pager:  '#nav',
            cleartypeNoBg:true
    });
```

You can select the shuffle animation here. I have mine set to top:15 and left:300

---

I'm trying to use the Cycle Plugin but I need it to shuffle to the right instead of the left. I've done this successfully by changing

```
opts.shuffle = opts.shuffle || {left:-w, top:15};
```

to

```
opts.shuffle = opts.shuffle || {left:+w, top:15};
```

The only problem is that the image I'm shuffling is quiet large and is creating a horizontal scroll bar during the transition between images. This doesn't happen when it's shuffling left and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Below is the snippet for the shuffle effect. Any help is appreciated!

```
// shuffle
$.fn.cycle.transitions.shuffle = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    var i, w = $cont.css('overflow', 'visible').width();
    $slides.css({left: 0, top: 0});
    opts.before.push(function(curr,next,opts) {
        $.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr,next,opts,true,true,true);
    });
    // only adjust speed once!
    if (!opts.speedAdjusted) {
        opts.speed = opts.speed / 2; // shuffle has 2 transitions
        opts.speedAdjusted = true;
    }
    opts.random = 0;
    opts.shuffle = opts.shuffle || {left:+w, top:15};
    opts.els = [];
    for (i=0; i < $slides.length; i++)
        opts.els.push($slides[i]);

    for (i=0; i < opts.currSlide; i++)
        opts.els.push(opts.els.shift());

    // custom transition fn (hat tip to Benjamin Sterling for this bit of sweetness!)
    opts.fxFn = function(curr, next, opts, cb, fwd) {
        var $el = fwd ? $(curr) : $(next);
        $(next).css(opts.cssBefore);
        var count = opts.slideCount;
        $el.animate(opts.shuffle, opts.speedIn, opts.easeIn, function() {
            var hops = $.fn.cycle.hopsFromLast(opts, fwd);
            for (var k=0; k < hops; k++)
                fwd ? opts.els.push(opts.els.shift()) : opts.els.unshift(opts.els.pop());
            if (fwd) {
                for (var i=0, len=opts.els.length; i < len; i++)
                    $(opts.els[i]).css('z-index', len-i+count);
            }
            else {
                var z = $(curr).css('z-index');
                $el.css('z-index', parseInt(z)+1+count);
            }
            $el.animate({left:0, top:0}, opts.speedOut, opts.easeOut, function() {
                $(fwd ? this : curr).hide();
                if (cb) cb();
            });
        });
    };
    opts.cssBefore = { display: 'block', opacity: 1, top: 0, left: 0 };
};
```

HTML

```
<div id="contentAreaJS" class="contentArea">
    <div id="s4" class="pics">
        <div id="navlist">
        <ul>
            <li id="mon"><a href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/ChilisLightbox_fajitas.png" style="text-decoration:none;" rel="shadowbox;width=500;height=400;"></a></li>
            <li id="tue"><a href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/ChilisLightbox_tacos.png" style="text-decoration:none;" rel="shadowbox;width=500;height=400;"></a></li>
            <li id="wed"><a href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/ChilisLightbox_chips.png" style="text-decoration:none;" rel="shadowbox;width=500;height=400;"></a></li>
            <li id="thur"><a href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/ChilisLightbox_dessert.png" style="text-decoration:none;" rel="shadowbox;width=500;height=400;"></a></li>
            <li id="fri"><a href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/ChilisLightbox_burger.png" style="text-decoration:none;" rel="shadowbox;width=500;height=400;"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <a href="https://www.chilistogo.com/Pages/Welcome.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/ChilispartyPlatters.png" height="237" width="769" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.chilis.com/EN/HappyHours/001.005.0609.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/ChilishappyHour.png" height="237" width="769" /></a>
        </div>     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post any html, but add `overflow: hidden` to the css of the container that is overflowing (getting the scrollbar). You may need to use the before/after hooks to control this so that page layout returns to normal after the transition completes.

Comment: It may be the before/after hooks. I tried changing the overflow and the image looks like it's disappearing behind an invisible wall.